# Cursor="Hand" Property is not Working Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

In this code Cursor="Hand" is not Working in WP8.1

```
 <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Cursor="Hand"/>
```

Comment: windows phone is a touch device, correct? then what do you expect to happen?

Comment: So its not necessary na..?

Comment: Windows Phone 8.1 seems to support Cursor ([from msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.cursor(v=vs.110).aspx) (ctrl + f "Plateformes")

Comment: @DeviPrasad i doubt it would be of much value. since if WP supports mouse input at all, there will not be many people using it.
Try making the contentpresenter look like something you can obviously tap on, and it will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone is touch-only.  The `Cursor` property has no effect.  If you want to make something look tappable, try adding a border around the control or altering the background color.

If you're wondering why `Cursor` is even in Windows Phone 8.1, then it is because Windows Phone and Windows 8.1 share controls (I.E. universal apps).  If you made an example Windows Store app and set a control's `Cursor` property, then you could see the effect by hovering over it with the cursor.